# One way binding doesn't work in AngularJS with setInterval

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, angularjs-scope

AngularJS is the first version of Angular and is not relevant any more. But as I started learning Angular4, I wanted to start right from AngularJS so that I can explore the  fundamentals  and objectives of the framework.

The below piece of code is to demonstrate one way data binding (changing the model re-renders the view) but unable to achieve it.

```
<p>One-Way Data-Binding: {{place}}</p>
```

is not updated every time there is change in the `"$scope.place"`. I suppose this paragraph should re render every time `$scope.place` value changes as we created one way data binding with place model.

is there any mistake with this code?

what are the best use cases for using one time binding (static pages?), one way binding(stock information) and two way binding(more interactive site)?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.18/angular.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('OneTimeBinding', []);
    app.controller('OneTimeBindingController', function($scope) {
      $scope.i = 0;
      $scope.places = [
        'Delhi', 'Gurgaon', 'Haryana', 'Punjab', 'Chennai', 'Noida', 'Mumbai', 'Pune', 'Nepal', 'Gujrat', 'Bihar', 'Uttrakhand'
      ];
      $scope.place = "Delhi";
      setInterval(function() {
          $scope.place = $scope.places[$scope.i];
          $scope.i++;
          if ($scope.i > 10) {
            $scope.i = 0;
          }
          console.log("$scope.place")
        },
        1000
      )
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="OneTimeBinding" ng-controller="OneTimeBindingController">
  <div>
    <h2>Difference between One-Time and One-Way Data Bindings</h2>
    <br />
    <p>One-Time Data-Binding: {{::place}}</p>
    <p>One-Way Data-Binding: {{place}}</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You've used `setInterval()` which runs outside the Angular digest cycle so Angular has no idea that things have changed and the view needs to be updated. Instead you should use the Angular version: [`$interval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval).

Comment: got it :).Thank you

Comment: could you please shed some light on the second part of the question too please?

Comment: Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `$interval`, since it's part of the AngularJS digest cycle. Inject it into your controller and replace the `setInterval`:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.18/angular.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('OneTimeBinding', []);
    app.controller('OneTimeBindingController', function($scope, $interval) {
      $scope.i = 0;
      $scope.places = [
        'Delhi', 'Gurgaon', 'Haryana', 'Punjab', 'Chennai', 'Noida', 'Mumbai', 'Pune', 'Nepal', 'Gujrat', 'Bihar', 'Uttrakhand'
      ];
      $scope.place = "Delhi";
      $interval(function() {
          $scope.place = $scope.places[$scope.i];
          $scope.i++;
          if ($scope.i > 10) {
            $scope.i = 0;
          }
          //console.log($scope.place)
        },
        1000
      )
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="OneTimeBinding" ng-controller="OneTimeBindingController">
  <div>
    <h2>Difference between One-Time and One-Way Data Bindings</h2>
    <br />
    <p>One-Time Data-Binding: {{::place}}</p>
    <p>One-Way Data-Binding: {{place}}</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

One-time data binding can be used to reduce the number of watchers. Usually when the pre-defined data that cannot be changed arrives from the back-end. Or when you list the data with `ng-repeat`, and you already have something that you want to display but don't want any watchers. (They are responsible for dynamic changes during digest cycle)

---

Since `setInterval` is not part of digest cycle, you can call the $digest manually with `$scope.$apply()`. It's a hack, and not recommended to be used. However it can be useful when working with additional DOM manipulating libraries like jQuery. Here is an example with manual digest:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.18/angular.js"></script>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('OneTimeBinding', []);
    app.controller('OneTimeBindingController', function($scope, $timeout) {
      $scope.i = 0;
      $scope.places = [
        'Delhi', 'Gurgaon', 'Haryana', 'Punjab', 'Chennai', 'Noida', 'Mumbai', 'Pune', 'Nepal', 'Gujrat', 'Bihar', 'Uttrakhand'
      ];
      $scope.place = "Delhi";

      setInterval(function() {
          $scope.place = $scope.places[$scope.i];
          $scope.i++;
          if ($scope.i > 10) {
            $scope.i = 0;
          }
          //console.log($scope.place)
          
          $scope.$apply(); // calling digest cycle
        },
        1000
      )

    });
  </script>
</head>

<body ng-app="OneTimeBinding" ng-controller="OneTimeBindingController">
  <div>
    <h2>Difference between One-Time and One-Way Data Bindings</h2>
    <br />
    <p>One-Time Data-Binding: {{::place}}</p>
    <p>One-Way Data-Binding: {{place}}</p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: could you please shed some light on the second part of the question too please?

Comment: I was kinda guessed that angular is able to update the view whenever 
it updates the model as the functionality to update the view is added to setter method of model.Although Angular is not aware of setInterval ,
cant Angular have a clue as setter of this model is called everytime setInterval executes?

Comment: @venkata added a comment about it. _tl;dr_: if the data doesn't change dynamically, use one-time binding. (Good uses: with the back-end data)

Comment: @venkata angularjs supports setInterval, but it doesn't display it. You would want to call a digest cycle manually for that case (see the edit)